# Mongoose - Take sum of [Number] and add new property to same document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have the following document in a Mongo database:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    question: "Blue or red?",
    __v: 0,
    votes: [9, 5]
}
```

I want to, in the back-end, get the total of votes, 14, (because 9 + 5 = 14) and append a new property on that document dynamically.  So in the end, it'll look like this:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    question: "Blue or red?",
    __v: 0,
    votes: [9, 5],
    totalVotes: 14
}
```

I researched how to do this, and found words like: Aggregate, unwind, etc.  I don't think those will help me because Aggregating in MongoDB is comparing the properties of documents, and I only want to modify the innards of a singular document relative to the properties of itself.

This was my "attempt" to do so:

```
var getTotal = function(arr){
   var total = 0;
   for(var i in arr) { total += arr[i]; }
   return total;
 };

Model.update({ $set: { totalVotes: getTotal(votes) }}, function(){
  console.log('Updated.');
});
```

Obviously `votes` is not defined, and this will result in an error.  How would I tell it to get the votes from the Model, and pass it in the `getTotal()` function?

Here's the schema of the Model, btw:

```
question: {type: String, required: true},
votes: [Number],
totalVotes: Number
```

Comment: what about using a virtual/computed attribute?

Comment: @Minato Are you talking about [this](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/virtuals.html)?  If so, that seems to be exactly what I need

Comment: @Mathew can you share your schema code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

supposing your `Schema` is `ExampleSchema`

```
var ExampleSchema = new Schema({
    question: {type: String, required: true},
    votes: [Number]
}, {
  toObject: {
     virtuals: true
  },
  toJSON: {
     virtuals: true 
  }
});
```

this will allow `virtuals` when querying for documents in mongoDB

Now for the implementation of virtual simple after declaring the schema.

```
ExampleSchema
.virtual('totalVotes')
.get(function () {
  return this.votes.reduce(function(currentValue, previousValue){
     return (currentValue + previousValue);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`.aggregate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate) method to do this:

From MongoDB 3.2 you can use the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#sum-aggregation) operator in the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage. More info in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#use-in-project-stage).

```
Model.aggregate(
    [
        { '$match': { '_id': 1 } },
        { "$project": { 
            "totalVotes": { "$sum": "$votes" } 
        }}
    ], 
    function(err, result) {
        Model.update(
            { '_id': result[0]['_id'] },  
            { '$set': { 'totalVotes': result[0]['totalVotes'] }},
            function(){
                console.log('Updated.');
            }
        );
    }
)
```

In previous version you need to first [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) the "votes" array.

```
Model.aggregate(
    [
        { "$match": { "_id": 1 } },
        { "$unwind": "$votes" }, 
        { "$group": { 
            "_id": "$_id",  
            "totalVotes": { "$sum": "$votes" } 
        }}
    ],
    function(err, result) {
        Model.update(
            { '_id': result[0]['_id'] },  
            { '$set': { 'totalVotes': result[0]['totalVotes'] }},
            function(){
                console.log('Updated.');
            }
        );
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Minato said I should try something called [virtuals](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/virtuals.html).  I did, and the outcome was good, except for one thing...

Here is the document:

```
 {
    _id: 1,
    question: "Blue or red?",
    __v: 0,
    votes: [9, 5]
}
```

I want to add an attribute called `totalVotes` with the value of `14`. (9 + 5 = 14)

So, consider this schema:

```
 var PollSchema = new Schema(
{
    question: {type: String, required: true},
    votes: [Number]
}, 
{
  toObject: {
    virtuals: true
  },
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true 
  }
}
);
```

Now, with that schema, I add the virtual attribute:

```
 PollSchema.virtual('totalVotes').get(function() {
   var total =  getTotal(this.votes);
   return total;
 });
```

And, I get this:

```
 {
    _id: 1,
    question: "Blue or red?",
    __v: 0,
    votes: [9, 5],
    totalVotes: "14[object Object]"
}
```

Now, apparently, the output is JSON so the "[object Object]" is apart of the string.  To remove it, I just use the `parseInt()` method...

```
PollSchema.virtual('totalVotes').get(function() {
   var total =  getTotal(this.votes);
  return parseInt(total);
});
```

And the output is **EXACTLY** what I've been wanting all along..

```
 {
    _id: 1,
    question: "Blue or red?",
    __v: 0,
    votes: [9, 5],
    totalVotes: 14
}
```

Comment: Good.. but you should use `Array` prototype methods ... :P

Comment: See my answer if you want to get the idea.. :P

Comment: You're getting that garbage in `totalVotes` because `votes` is a `MongooseDocumentArray`, not a plain JS array and your `for...in` is picking up other enumerable properties besides the indexes. Which is why it's typically a [bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea) to use `for...in` to iterate over arrays.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Thanks for the tip.  I just got that `for...in` loop when I looked for how to get the sum of an array.  I just now researched the `reduce()` array method, and knowing how simple it is to process an array from left to right and reducing it down to a single number, that seems to be a much better approach.